# Nginx reverse proxy same listen port to multiple unique location ports

Tags: nginx, ssl, reverse-proxy, port, proxypass

I've been trying to find a solution whereby I am listening to port 443 externally and want to pass the results to two unique internal ports (80/90). I've researched a number of options but they all seem to focus on multiple unique externally facing ports to re-route traffic to corresponding internal ports. It appears as though Streams may be the answer but I'm unsure how to make it all work - https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

Here is my existing Nginx conf:

```
 server {
        # ssl
        listen  443 ssl  http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io;

        location / {
                #http trafic
                proxy_pass https://192.168.86.77;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                #ws support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                server_tokens off;
        }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io/fullchain.pem;                     
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io/privkey.pem;                     

}

server {
    if ($host = pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }                     

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io;
    return 404;                     

}
```

I'm trying to do something like the code shown below, though I know that it would be problematic in the sense that I'm not certain how Nginx would determine how the request on port 443 would be directed to port 80 or 90 internally.

```
server {
        # ssl
        listen  443 ssl  http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io;

        location / {
                #http trafic
                proxy_pass https://192.168.86.77;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                #ws support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                server_tokens off;
        }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io/fullchain.pem;                     
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io/privkey.pem;                     

}

server {
        # ssl
        listen  443 ssl  http2;
        listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io;

        location / {
                #http trafic
                proxy_pass https://192.168.86.77:90;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                #ws support
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                server_tokens off;
        }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io/fullchain.pem;                     
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io/privkey.pem;                     

}

server {
    if ($host = pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }                     

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name pixelstreaming.mobiusnode.io;
    return 404;                     

}
```

There must be a better way and I'm hoping I'll find some help on these forums. Perhaps there's a combination of the elements included above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. If you want to send the data to both ports at the same time: not possible and even if it would it would be unclear which of the responses to send back. If you want to send it either to one or the other: you need to specify the condition which should be used to decide between these ports.

Comment: please fix your question. it is mixed with your problem and a 100% misunderstanding of nginx configuration. the second server block redirect the request to the ip on port 90,and that is if i understand what you want, else use a subdir or second sub-domain to use different ports

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you are correct in that I wish to specify one or the other based on a condition. The condition would be fairly simple, if the request is calling 80, then go to 80, if calling 90 the use the block pointing to 90. Does this make sense? I think my question may be over complicating the matter.

Comment: @MarkCichy: *"if the request is calling 80, ..."* - I have no idea what you mean with this. Do you mean some part of the path, like `https://example.com/80/` or what exactly do you mean by this?

Comment: My apologies, @SteffenUllrich I was referring to port 80. The application we are running is ALWAYS running on port 80, but we are enforcing encryption via Nginx through 443 (as illustrated in server block). The application on port 80 will sometimes pass the user onto port 90 moving from one service to another - all on the same internal IP/server.

Comment: *"... The application on port 80 will sometimes pass the user onto port 90  ..."* - if the application redirects the user to port 90 then the user will try this and not end up at the nginx in the first place. If you don't want this you need to rewrite the redirect, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568452/modifying-a-location-header-with-nginx-proxy-pass. But of course you need to have something to rewrite to instead of port 90. And this must differ from the normal URL so that the server can distinguish what should be passed to port 80 and what to port 90.